# Name exported files with names list from txt-file using command prompt

Tags: list, text, filenames, rename, command-prompt

I have a tons of files and I want to convert them to other format using command prompt.
After exporting each of converted files program needs to name it.
I have a txt-documnet, that contains a list of future file-names.
So, I really need to name exported files one by one using first string name, then second string name, then third and so on.
EXAMPLE I have files to import in the directory

> 00001.umg
>   00002.umg
>   00003.umg
>   00004.umg
>   00005.umg
>   00006.umg
>   00007.umg
>   (and so on)

I have a txt document looking like this

```
    Great name.brt
    Wonderful.brt
    Most beautiful.brt
    Beautiful File.brt
    Random File.brt
    Define.brt
    Excellent file.brt
    ...
```

(and so on)

So, after convertion I need to have exported files named like string in txt document in proper direction. First file must take first TXT string name, second - second string.....

Thank you!

Comment: With what are you getting stuck? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I do not understand how to make the command line automatically assign appropriate names from a txt-file list. By the way, the command line has the following form
briok.exe <input file name> -c <output file name>

Comment: Your nickname seems to indicate that your mother tongue isn't English.  If your filenames use any non-Latin character sets or Unicode then it can fail. Tell the readers now if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you, foxidrive! Yes, filenames mostly contains Cyrillic characters like ь,б,ю etc.